# Swift передача данных в Notification Content Extension(NCE)

Tags: swift, уведомления, фреймворк

Всем привет. В процессе изучения swift столкнулся с тем, что нужно передать уже инициализированный класс в NCE. И тут я не очень понимаю какой подход использовать. Если просто передавать данные между VC то можно использовать сигвеи, Notification center или что то еще но в случае с NCE у меня эти способы не работают. local notification, которое отправляется из ViewController может быть доставлено через 30 секунд, 5 минут или 1 час. Я пытаюсь сказать, что если я правильно понимаю, то на момент отправки уведомления NotificationViewController еще не существует, а будет создан только когда сообщение будет доставлено, но когда оно будет доставлено уже не будет существовать ViewController (пользователь банально может закрыть приложение). Пытался так же использовать синглтон, но тоже не работает из за выше указанной причины.

Прошу подсказать каким образом в таких случаях принято передавать данные. И сказать, если мои представления о жизненном цикле приложения ошибочны. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем не знаю, на сколько это правильное решения, но  я записываю данные в **user default**  и извлекаю их в фреймворке. Объект храниться временно, так что место в памяти не занимает. + Теперь работает даже если закрыть основное приложение.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим у вас вторая вьюха `ViewController2`.

Можно через `prepare for segue` естественно у вас в `Storyboard` должны быть связи между вьюхами

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   let dvc = segue.destination as! ViewController2
   dvc.title = "some text" //тут подразумевается что у ViewController2 
   //есть переменная title и таким образом ты передаешь данные с 
   //этого контролера на ViewController2
}
```

Есть другой способ:

Допустим у вас есть кнопка по тапу на которой вам надо реализовать переход и передачу данных.

```
@IBAction func tapBtb(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
    //обязательно в сториборде в пункте identify дайте название ViewController2

    vc2.title = "some text"

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    //так реализовывается переход
    //это сработает если у вашей вьюхи присутствует UINavigationController
}
```

Comment: Оба способа пробовал с самого начала, но результатов не дают. В **prepare for segue** не могу создать связь между вьюхами, потому что они в разных сторибордах. А во втором методе у меня не осуществляется переход на прямую,  по нажатию на кнопку отправляется уведомление (скажем оно должно прейти  через 30 минут). Только когда приходит уведомления появляется возможность открыть кастомный интерфейс и вывести полученные данные.

Comment: залей на гитхаб, и скинь ссылку, я гляну

Comment: https://github.com/dimabruno/swift-notification_extension_test.git